# Using supabase_flutter package to add new users using email and password

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages, supabase

I am learning to use supabase for my backend and I see that there is a lot of examples of how to add new users using the dart package `supabase` [[docs]](https://pub.dev/packages/supabase). However, I wanted to know how I can add new users (using their email and password) using the flutter package `supabase_flutter` [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/supabase_flutter). (Email confirmation has been turned off)

The docs include authentication examples, but I cant find how to sign up new users using this package. Is this meant to be a package used alongside the supabase dart package to make code cleaner for certain features or is it an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`supabase_flutter` is an alternative of `supabase` package when you want to develop Flutter applications using Supabase. When you are using `supabase_flutter`, you don't need to include `supabase` in your pubspec.yaml.

Using `supabase_flutter`, you can sign up users like this:

```dart
final supabase = Supabase.instance.client;

final res = await supabase.auth.signUp('example@email.com',　'example-password');

final user = res.data?.user;
final error = res.error;
```

You can read more on the official docs [here](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/dart/auth-signup).

Sorry for the confusion there. We are in the process of rearranging things to make it more obvious for the developer to use `supabase_flutter` when developing Flutter applications.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I enjoy using Supabase. I look forward to seeing more information and worked examples on how to use the supabase_flutter package in the near future